# How can i align right navbar-toggler with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

how can i align navbar-toogler to the right in this case?
btw i'm using Bootstrap 4.1.3.

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
          <!-- Here is what i need help -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
              
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using Bootstrap 4? The Navbar markup shown is for Bootstrap 3. [Read the Navbar docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) and the toggler position is aligned right by default.

Comment: If i see the correct one, it is not. Look at "External Content" that in the end of the page, it is in left.

Comment: Try any of the other examples: https://www.codeply.com/go/9oD8pkUH13 -- you're not using standard Bootstrap 4 Navbar markup. There is no `navbar-header` anymore.

Comment: how can i add toggler to that example? 
edit: sorry, it already has toggler, i see it now. thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following structure for navbar to ensure that the toggler comes on right side. Please note that while using bootstrap try to stick with their given format of HTML.

Please check the valid HTML structure here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#nav

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: I did it but it aligned all items right but i want to alight brand logo left and toggler righ.

Comment: @SefaÖzçelik I have updated the answer. Please check it now.